# I dont know how to set criteria for COUNT function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to make a table that will show me the average total value of the entered data.

Column A, we have dates from 1 to 31.

Column B, we enter values for each date.

Column C has another set of dats

Column D has Sum of Col B & C, during the month I enter values.

On Sundays nothing is entered so the SUM remains 0.

The average value must include that day. However, the AVERAGE function takes values that have not yet been entered and extracts an average for them as well.

In other words, if a value is entered for only 1 and 2 dates, it must consider only those two dates and not the other dates by the end of the month.

**Edit:** I need to find the average value of column D (in the first post I said C. I apologize for that). I need to get values from Date `1.11` to `15.11` because there is input until `15.11`.

[image]

Comment: Could you please [Edit] your post & share some sample data with us !!

Comment: You may use any of these,, `=AVERAGEIF(C2:C31,"<>0")`  or  `=SUM(C2:C31)/COUNTIF(C2:C31,">0")`

Comment: @RajeshS You beat me by posting the comment when I was begin to post an answer. I think you should post an answer (then I will delete mine).

Answer (score 0):

*You may use either of the formulas:*

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(AND(A2:A31>=E1)*(A2:A31<=F1),D2:D31,"<>0"),D2:D31)}
```

- Finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Cell `E1` start date (`1.11`) and `F1` has end date (`15.11`).

  ```
  =AVERAGEIFS(D2:D31, D2:D31,"<>0",A2:A31, "<=11/15/19", A2:A31, ">=11/01/19")
  ```

**N.B.** Both formula ignore ZERO in Column D.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*